# android, matcher.appendReplacement(sb, '$8') through ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, regex

This is running on Adroid 4.2.2. Using regex Pattern and Matcher with appendReplacement().
What it does is to replace some place holder in the html string received from remote source with some customized the data.

It is strange every other string put in is fine until '$8'. With any number follow the '$' it will throw exception. With number only or '$' only does not throw.
Here is simplified code snippet.

```
            String patternStr = "(PlaceHolder)";
    final Pattern cPattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr, Pattern.DOTALL);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    Matcher matcher = cPattern.matcher(srcData);

    try{
    while(matcher.find()) {

        String newData = "<span>Price: $8 </span> ";
        try {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, newData);  //<== throws

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(ex);
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
```

The exception show:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=16
java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:353)
java.util.regex.Matcher.appendEvaluated(Matcher.java:137)
java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:110)
```

Anything special with the '$' followed by number?

Thanks!

EDIT: The http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29 explained!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the oracle page for Matcher: [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

Try escaping the $